# Detaching all entities of T to get fresh data

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

Lets take an example where there are two type of entites loaded: Product and Category, Product.CategoryId -> Category.Id. We have available CRUD operations on products (not Categories).

If on another screen Categories are updated (or from another user in the network), we would like to be able to reload the Categories, while preserving the context we currently use, since we could be in the middle of editing data, and we do not want changes to be lost (and we cannot depend on saving, since we have incomplete data).

Since there is no easy way to tell EF to get fresh data (added, removed and modified), we thought of twp possible ways:

1) Getting products attached to context, and categories detached from context. This would mean that we loose the ability to access Product.Category.Name, which we do sometimes require, so we would need to manually resolve it (example when printing data).

2) detaching / attaching all Categories from current context.

```
Context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity.GetType() == typeof(T)).ForEach(x => x.State = EntityState.Detached);
```

And then reload the categories, which will get fresh data. Do you find any problem with this second approach? We understand that this will require all constraints to be put on foreign keys, and not navigation properties, since when detaching all Categories, Product.Category navigation properties would be reset to null also. Also, there could be a potential performance problem, which we did not test, since there could be couple of thousand products loaded, and all would need to resolve navigation property when reloading.

Which of the two do you prefer, and is there a better way (EF6 + .NET 4.0)?

Comment: You should include some more info: what kind of info is it? where and how are you instancing the context? But, in general is not good idea to have very long lived DbContexts.

Comment: @JotaBe This is a WPF app, so it is a normal to have a Context-Per-Screen instance, so as long as the screen lives, Context should also live. I am not sure about what did you mean by "what kind of info is it"?

Comment: I'm sorry it was a typo. I meant to say "what kind of app is it?" As you say, it's important to know it's a WPF app, because that means long lived DbContexts. I'm adding the tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to try

```
/// <summary>
/// Reloads the entity from the database overwriting any property values with values from the database.
///             The entity will be in the Unchanged state after calling this method.
/// 
/// </summary>
public void Reload(){
  ....
}
```

sample call

```
     public virtual void Reload(TPoco poco) {

        if (poco == null) {
          // wtf....        
        }
        try {
            Context.Entry<TPoco>(poco).Reload();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            //... whatever
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So if I am not mistaken, the advice is to run hundreds of queries to db to reload each record individually? As I said, it is a products CRUD screen, and there could be hundreds / thousands of products. I really cannot know what products are changed on network in the meantime, so I can reload only particular products.

Comment: Hi Goran, i think you best decide the "refresh" strategy. At some point you also need to consider the optimistic versus pessimistic concurrency pattern.Essentially the longer the context lives, the more concurrency issues you have. So there is a trade off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second level cache implementation, for example:

- [SECOND LEVEL CACHE FOR EF 6.1](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/03/20/second-level-cache-for-ef-6-1/)

Note: it's no longer beta version. the 1.0.0 what released on 2013/8/27. There are also other implementations, including some for older versions of EF.

Comment: This is a client->database aaplication, and second level cache would be applied to each PC, and I need to fetch/reload the changes made by network users, on different PCs.